# Keep getting Error Message during System Updates

Tags: clamav

I've been getting the following Error Message, every time i update the System or any other installed App.

```
Setting up clamav-daemon (0.102.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) ... touch:
cannot touch '/var/log/clamav/clamav.log': No such file or directory

dpkg: error processing package clamav-daemon (--configure):  installed
clamav-daemon package post-installation script subprocess returned
error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing: 
clamav-daemon E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Thanks Guys...

Answer (score 0):

maybe a permission issue or a buggy installer, try to help the installer by creating this folder first by

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/clamav/
```

and run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall clamav-daemon
```